# How to add Text dynamically in CKEditor 4 at the position where the cursor is currently?

Tags: reactjs, ckeditor4.x

I have a screen where the user needs to fill in a rich document (I'm using Ckeditor4) and at some point he can click on a list, and the item in that list should appear at the current cursor position in the rich text. I saw that it is possible to do it using JQuery, but I didn't find anything similar with React. Can anyone recommend me some documentation for this?

Here is the code I've made so far.

```
import { CKEditor } from "ckeditor4-react";

const TextEditor = () => {

  function handleClick(fruit:string){
      //add to CKEditor
  }


  return (
    <>
      <div>
        {["Apple", "Banana", "Grape", "Pineapple"].map((item) => (
          <button key={item} onClick={()=>handleClick(item)}></button>
        ))}
      </div>

      <CKEditor initData="<p>This is an example CKEditor 4 WYSIWYG editor instance.</p>" />
    </>
  );
};

export default TextEditor;
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve this you can make use of State in setting your initial data and changing the state value on Click. I've done an implementation here using React Class Components: https://codesandbox.io/s/ckeditor-5-react-forked-5q7jmk?file=/src/index.js

For your case

```
import {useState} from 'react'
import { CKEditor } from "ckeditor4-react";

const TextEditor = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState('')

  function handleClick(fruit:string){
     setData(fruit)
  }


  return (
    <>
      <div>
        {["Apple", "Banana", "Grape", "Pineapple"].map((item) => (
          <button key={item} onClick={()=>handleClick(item)}></button>
        ))}
      </div>

      <CKEditor initData={data} />
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: Hello Brother.
That's almost what I want, I managed to get to this point, but I don't want that when I click on the item, all my text is replaced. I need that when clicking, the text of the clicked item appears in the place where the cursor is currently, concatenating with the text that has already been typed by the user.

Comment: If you would like to append to the last word/line of the CKEditor data then you can do that by spreading the state (I've updated the sandbox to reflect how this is done)

But to get the cursor position and update in that particular position, you would have to make use of the CKEDitor API (Not so familiar with this bit)

Comment: Yes, I need to add exactly where the cursor is. I will study the API documentation here, thanks.